# Update/Filter Nodes and Links in D3 Force Network

Tags: svg, d3.js, data-visualization, force-layout

I'm having difficulties updating my D3 force network. The goal is to have the possibility to redraw the graph with filtered data. For simplicity I provided the code example below with two Dummydatasets (complete and filtered) which can be chosen with buttons. But instead of redrawing the graph it just keeps appending new svg-Elements besides the already existing. I guess it has something to do with calling the entire showData function again and again. Though I tried different solutions it keeps appending the svgs besides or the g-elements on top of each other. Here's the code and the data:

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="network.js"></script>
    <script src="getData.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="loadData('dummyData1.json')">Data1</button>
    <button onclick="loadData('dummyData2.json')">Data2</button>
    <div id="network"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

***getData.js***

```
let store = {}
function loadData(url) {
    console.log(url)
    return Promise.all([
        d3.json(url)
    ]).then(datasets => {
        store.graph = datasets[0];
        showData(store.graph)
        return store;
    })
   
}
```

***network.js***

```
function showData (data){

        var toggle = 0;
        width=500;
        height=500;
        
        var linkedByIndex = {};
        data.links.forEach(function(d) {
            linkedByIndex[d.source + ',' + d.target] = 1;
            linkedByIndex[d.target + ',' + d.source] = 1;
        });

        
        let simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                .force("link", d3.forceLink().id((d) => d.id).distance(10))
                .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(d => -20))
                .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            
        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(data.nodes)
        .range(['#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a','#984ea3','#ff7f00','#ffff33','#a65628'])
        
        svg = d3.select("#network").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)

        var g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "everything")

        var link = g.append("g")
            .selectAll(".link")
                            
        var node = g.append("g")
            .selectAll(".node")
                
        var drag_handler = d3.drag()
            .on("start", drag_start)
            .on("drag", drag_drag)
            .on("end", drag_end);   
            
        drag_handler(node);
       
        var zoom_handler = d3.zoom()
            .on("zoom", zoom_actions);
        
        zoom_handler(svg); 
        
        update();
        
        /** Functions **/
        function update() {
        
        node = node.data(data.nodes)
        
        node.exit().remove()
        
        var newNode = node.enter().append("circle")
                .attr('class', 'node')
                .attr("r", 5)
                .attr('fill', function(d) {return(color(d.country))})
                .on('click', function(d, i) {
                    if (toggle == 0) {
                        // Ternary operator restyles links and nodes if they are adjacent.
                        d3.selectAll('.link').style('stroke-opacity', function (l) {
                            return l.target == i || l.source == i ? 1 : 0.1;
                        });
                        d3.selectAll('.node').style('opacity', function (n) {
                            return neighboring(n, i) ? 1 : 0.1;
                        });
                        d3.select(this).style('opacity', 1);
                        toggle = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        // Restore nodes and links to normal opacity.
                        d3.selectAll('.link').style('stroke-opacity', '0.3');
                        d3.selectAll('.node').style('opacity', '1');
                        toggle = 0;
                    }
                })
        
        node = node.merge(newNode)
        
        link = link.data(data.links)
        
        link.exit().remove();
        
        var newLink = link.enter().append("line")
                .attr('class', 'link')
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.3)
        
        link = link.merge(newLink)
        
        simulation
        .nodes(data.nodes)
        .on("tick", tickActions);
        
        simulation.force("link")
        .links(data.links);
        
        simulation.alpha(1).alphaTarget(0).restart();
        
            
        }
      
        function drag_start(event, d) {
         if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }
        
        function drag_drag(event, d) {
          d.fx = event.x;
          d.fy = event.y;
        }
        
        function drag_end(event, d) {
          if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
          d.fx = null;
          d.fy = null;
        }
        
        function neighboring(a, b) {
            return linkedByIndex[a.id + ',' + b.id];
        }
        
        //Zoom functions 
        function zoom_actions(event, d){
            g.attr("transform", event.transform)
        }
        
        function tickActions() {
            
            node
                .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
                
           
            link
                .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
        } 
            }
```

***dummyData1.json***

```
{"nodes": [
    {"id":1, "country":"Germany"},
    {"id":2, "country":"UK"},
    {"id":3, "country":"USA"},
    {"id":4, "country":"China"},
    {"id":5, "country":"Greece"},
    {"id":6, "country":"Brazil"}
],
"links": [
    {"source": 2, "target": 4},
    {"source": 1, "target": 4},
    {"source": 3, "target": 5},
    {"source": 6, "target": 1},
    {"source": 5, "target": 4},
    {"source": 1, "target": 2},
    {"source": 2, "target": 3}
]}
```

***dummyData2.json***

```
{"nodes": [
    {"id":1, "country":"Germany"},
    {"id":2, "country":"UK"},
    {"id":3, "country":"USA"},
    {"id":4, "country":"China"}
],
"links": [
    {"source": 2, "target": 4},
    {"source": 1, "target": 4},
    {"source": 1, "target": 2},
    {"source": 2, "target": 3}
]}
```

Thanks in advance:-)